# How do I build Cassandra from GitHub source?

Tags: cassandra

I found this repo on github: https://github.com/apache/cassandra

And I would like to import it into intellij and build it in order to run some code locally that I want to build on top of this github code. But there are no instructions for building it.

Where are the instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for taking interest in writing Cassandra code.

The instructions for building Cassandra from source code including IDE integration is documented in the [Contributing to Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/development/index.html) page on the official [Apache Cassandra website](https://cassandra.apache.org). There are instructions for IntelliJ, NetBeans and Eclipse.

It's not as straightforward as we would like because everyone's laptop/desktop is different so I would recommend you join the ASF Slack to get help in real-time from other Cassandra contributors in the `#cassandra-dev` channel. For details, see the [Community](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/community.html) section of the Cassandra website. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: How do I join ASF slack? I tried and it said that I must have an apache account or something, is it hard to make one?

Comment: Here's an invitation link that's valid for today -- https://join.slack.com/t/the-asf/shared_invite/zt-1jj1hp4w2-zumXSP4378hRaDFLqKTXWA. Cheers!

Comment: I've added you the #cassandra-dev channel on ASF Slack. Cheers!

Comment: Why does Cassandra still use ant as build tool?